# How to check if Tornado already listen url?

Tags: python, tornado

How to check if application in Tornado listen some url ?
I need to listen lot off urls, for new game I create new and add programmatically handler for that url, but I first need to check. How to check if Tornado already listen url?

Answer (score 2):

There is no public interface to find out whether a path is currently mapped in a Tornado Application.  In general, you shouldn't be calling add_handlers after startup anyway - instead, add a wildcard rule (like `(r'/game/(.*)', GameHandler)`) and then in `GameHandler` you can check whether the requested game exists or not (and if not, `raise HTTPError(404)`).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need a fine-grained access to the active games, so better keep them in your domain model.

Still, you can examine `tornado.web.Application.handlers` of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never; If I understand your question correctly, you may achieve your goal by a real request to the server. Here is an example with `requests` library:

```
response = requests.get("http://localhost:8888")
error_msg = "Server Responses with {}".format(response)
self.assertTrue(response.ok, error_msg)
```